# Hooking Windows Kernel Dispatcher for System Calls

Tags: windows, hook, system-calls, sysenter

I'm trying to hook `SYSENTER` dispatch function from the kernel and during the past few days I was studying about what happens when a program executes `SYSENTER` and wants to enter to kernel then I realized `IA32_SYSENTER_EIP` and `IA32_SYSENTER_ESP` are responsible to set the kernel `RIP` and `RSP` after `SYSENTER`.

Yesterday I read Intel Software Developer Manuals about `SWAPGS` :

> SWAPGS exchanges the current GS base register value with the value contained in MSR address C0000102H (IA32_KERNEL_GS_BASE). The SWAPGS instruction is a privileged instruction intended for use by system software.
>
> When using SYSCALL to implement system calls, there is no kernel stack
>   at the OS entry point. Neither is there a straightforward method to
>   obtain a pointer to kernel structures from which the kernel stack
>   pointer could be read. Thus, the kernel cannot save general purpose
>   registers or reference memory.

From the second paragraph, `there is no kernel stack at the OS entry point` seems that OS kernel executes `SWAPGS` to set the `GS` and then get the kernel stack pointer but as I read, in a `SYSENTER` kernel RIP(EIP) and RSP (ESP) should set from `IA32_SYSENTER_EIP` and `IA32_SYSENTER_ESP` so the kernel has its stack pointer in `IA32_SYSENTER_ESP` !

My Questions :

1. If kernel stack address should come from GS then what's the purpose of `IA32_SYSENTER_ESP`?
2. What are differences between `AMD LSTAR (0xC0000082)` and `IA32_SYSENTER_EIP`? I ask it because I saw Windows set 0xc0000082 on my Intel processor.
3. Is there any special problem with hooking kernels SYSENTER dispatcher?It's because whenever I put a breakpoint in Windows function which is responsible for dispatching SYSENTER calls (KiSystemCall64Shadow) on a remote debugging machine (Not VM) then it causes BSOD with UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP.

Comment: IA32_SYSENTER_ESP is for sysenter. Swapgs is needed for syscall